# How to fill the area between two curves on a polar plot

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates

I have the code below. It creates a MATLAB polar plot with two curves (see picture attached). How can I fill the area between these curves? The normal fill option does not work since this is polar.[image]

```
t=data(1,:);
a1=data(11,:);
b1=data(12,:);
r_scale=50;
line_width=2;
font_size=12;
marker = 3;
figure(1)
polarplot(t,a1,'-or','MarkerSize',2)
hold on
polarplot(t,b1,'-ok','MarkerSize',2)
hold on
```

Comment: How about get [X, Y] for both polygons, and then fill the outer curve with the color you want, then fill the inner one with transparent color? I think other people may have better idea.

Comment: Could you show me how to do this?

Comment: [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/66224) is a possible solution.

Comment: I Was hoping someone could provide assistance specifically with my problem. I have found others online which use equations and such to generate data. Mine are specific data points.